# Changing the Z perspective in processing

Tags: processing

I'm fairly new to processing but I am having trouble shifting the z position on one of my line sets.

The x axis lines look as I need it to, but I am basically trying to bring up the Y set of lines so they arent just going downwards but are more linked up with the first set of lines. I hope I'm making sense, It's kind of hard to explain. Thanks!

Edit: Basically what Im trying to make is a tiled floor.

```
int grid = 80; 



void setup() {
  size (1024, 900, P3D);
}

void draw() {

  int movement = mouseY-500;


  background(0);
  strokeWeight(2.5);
  stroke(100, 255, 0, 60);

  //floorx
  for (int i = 0; i < width; i+=grid) {
    line (i , height/2 , 0, i ,  height, 5000);

 }

  //floory
  for (int i = 0; i < height; i+=grid) {
   line (0, i + height/2, 0, width, i + height/2,0 );
 }





}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! remember that you're asking normal people like yourself for help, so be nice to them: format your code nicely so it's easy for them to read through it in order to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The lines look okay to me. Can you show us a screenshot of what you're seeing compared to a mockup of what you're expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want the grid to appear more geometrically correct. To achieve this you need different distances between the horizontal lines.

Try this in your floory part:

```
grid = 40;
//floory
for (int i = 0; i < height; i+=grid) {
    line (0, i + height/2, 0, width, i + height/2, 0 );
    grid += 20;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate this and sorry I had a hard time being clear haha but I guess you figured out what i was asking. I have a better understanding for what i was trying to convey now.